# AssertionError: Gaps in blk ref_locs when attempting to drop rows with `np.nan`

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame of shape 12k * 150. One of the columns is `Lat`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Lat': [83.21, np.nan, np.nan, 83.42],
                   'Lon' [-19.21, np.nan, np.nan, -20.56]
                 })
```

This is for illustration not a reproducible example, as my DataFrame is fairly large and I don't exactly know what's causing the issue.

I am trying to drop the rows with `np.nan` and get this error when I tried, `drop.na`, `mask = (df['Lat'].isna())` and other methods.

```
/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in _consolidate_inplace(self)
   1686             self._is_consolidated = True
   1687             self._known_consolidated = True
-> 1688             self._rebuild_blknos_and_blklocs()
   1689 
   1690 

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/internals.pyx in pandas._libs.internals.BlockManager._rebuild_blknos_and_blklocs()

AssertionError: Gaps in blk ref_locs
```

Answer (score 0):

use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=dropna#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) with a subset attribute

if you need to include other columns to consider, add those in the subset list.

```
df.dropna(subset=['Lat'])
```

alternately,

```
df.loc[df['Lat'].notna()]
```

```
    id  Lat     Lon
0   0   83.21   -19.21
3   3   83.42   -20.56
```

Comment: I get the `AssertionError: Gaps in blk ref_locs` error when I run this on my dataframe of shape `12k * 150`.

Comment: got the exact same error. Not sure what's causing the error. when i run `df['Lat'].isna().sum()`, the result is 9.

Comment: something to do with the indexes on your DF. check this out, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19351

Comment: since error is not reproducible with the sample data I have. you can try the workaround and see if that resolves it for you. the issue has to do with the index value

Comment: Running `df.index.names` i get `FrozenList([None])`, not sure if that's expected.  `icols = df.index.names  df.reset_index().set_index(icols)` <-- this throws `IndexError: tuple index out of range`, simply printing `df.index` gives `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=12853, step=1)`

Comment: how about reassigning values to the index like  df.set_index( np.arange(0, len(df)))  , can you try that?